# in order to send parameters to stored procedure in loop

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have a function which name is **fnc_FiderSumOfAboneSayisi** that can be sent an integer value with parameter **@prm_fiderid**. so I have a table which name is **fider_data** that has ID column.
Now I want to in order  to send fider_data ID column value as parameter to my fnc_FiderSumOfAboneSayisi function as a loop.

how can i do that ??

----------FUNCTION

> alter function  fnc_FiderSumOfAboneSayisi @prm_fiderid as int
>
> returns int
>
> as
>
> begin
>
> declare @parent int = @prm_fiderid;
>
> declare @SUM int;
>
> with q As(
>
> ```
> select * from fider_data    where ParentId = @parent
>
> union all
>
> select lc.*    from q
>
> join fider_data lc on lc.ParentId = q.ID )
> ```
>
> SELECT @SUM=(SELECT  sum(SAYI) FROM    q where  ID<33000) return @SUM
>
> end

----------TABLE fider_data

ADI ID

TM 1    1

TM 2    2

TM 3    3

TM 4    4

TM 5    5

TM 6    6

TM 7    7

TM 8    8

TM 9    9

.

.

.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
DECLARE @id INT

SET @id = (SELECT TOP 1.ID FROM fider_data ORDER BY ID ASC)



WHILE @id IS NOT NULL

BEGIN
    SELECT  fnc_FiderSumOfAboneSayisi @prm_fiderid = @id

    SET @id = (SELECT TOP 1.ID FROM fider_data WHERE ID > @id ORDER BY ID ASC)  

END
```